# If $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$, then $\frac{df}{dx}$ for $x\not\in(-1,1)$ is not real or is simply undefined. Do such values have meaning?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I was reviewing some trig derivatives for an upcoming test and came across what I think is an

interesting question.

> Consider $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$. Then $\dfrac{df}{dx}$ for $x$ not in $(-1,1)$ yields a  value that is not real or is simply undefined.

Are these non-real solutions valid?  Either way, what do they even mean? Surely the fact that we can arrive at these values means something.

Comment: Well, the $\arcsin$ function can be extended to be *complex-analytic* (differentiable) bar a few exceptional (branch) regions. The derivative of a complex function does not relate to slope in the sense you’re used to, but it’s basically the same thing

Comment: Implicit in the comment above, but maybe it should be stated explicitly, is that $f(x)$ itself is "not real or is simply undefined" for those values of $x$, until you do the analytic continuation, so it shouldn't come as a surprise that its derivative has the same properties.